# How to wrap posts into divs?

Tags: jquery

Does anyone know how I can turn this:

```
<div id="mySlides">

    <?php query_posts('showposts=4&cat=11'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="< ?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>

<div id="myController">
    <span class="jFlowControl">1</span>
    <span class="jFlowControl">2</span>
    <span class="jFlowControl">3</span>
    <span class="jFlowControl">4</span>
</div>

<span class="jFlowPrev">Prev</span>
<span class="jFlowNext">Next</span>

<div class="clear">
```

Into:

```
<div id="mySlides">
<div id="slide1"><img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="Slide 1 jFlow Plus" />
 <span><h2>Welcome to the First Slide!</h2><p>We hope you enjoy the jFlow Plus Slider - a light-weight slider for your web design needs. <a href="#" title="Coolness" class="readmore">Read More!</a></p></span>
</div>
<div id="slide2"><img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="Slide 2 jFlow Plus" />
 <span><h2>Hey you made it to the Second Slide!</h2><p>We Know you enjoy this plugin... it's not too hard to implement, right? <a href="#" title="Coolness" class="readmore">Read More!</a></p></span>
</div>
<div id="slide3"><img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="Slide 3 jFlow Plus" />
 <span><h2>Woah You're on the Third Slide</h2><p>You've completed quiet the journey! All the way from slide 1 to slide 3... congratulations! <a href="#" title="Coolness" class="readmore">Read More!</a></p></span>
 </div>
 </div>  

<div id="myController">
   <span class="jFlowControl"></span>
   <span class="jFlowControl"></span>
   <span class="jFlowControl"></span>
</div>
```

I need to wrap each post preview in to divs so jFlow can then organise them into slides like http://dre.im/how-to-create-a-jquery-carousel-with-wordpress-posts/

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably a more-involved question, but I'll try to answer it as-is. The following code will wrap each post's content in a `<div>`:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div id="slide<?php the_ID(); ?>>

            // Post content - i.e. your slider image - goes here

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now, the inherent problem here is: where is your slide content, and how are the slide images added to that content? Are you using a custom post type? Are you using featured images? Are you using custom post meta?

We'll need considerably more information in order to specify exactly how to output *your specific content* using the Loop.

**EDIT**

Following up on your comment, this code will use the featured image as the slider image (and assumes you have created a custom image size, `slider-image`, to use in the slider), and the Post Title as the slider title, and the Post Excerpt as the slider text:

**EDIT 2**

Now including a post permalink around the slider image:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div id="slide<?php the_ID(); ?>>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'slider-image' ); ?>
            </a>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

        </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

That should give you a reasonable approximation of your example markup.

Comment: I was hoping to use the featured images

Comment: By "hoping to use" featured images: does that mean you *are using* featured images, or want to know *how* to use featured images?

Comment: Also: see edited answer, incorporating featured images.

Comment: Thanks Chip, now using the featured image function from the functions.php file but not sure how to make the slide images into links that take the user to the featured post?

Comment: You just need to wrap the call to `the_post_thumbnail()` in anchor tags with `the_permalink()` as the href. See edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an ending div tag before `<?php endwhile; ?>`.

So:

```
<div id="mySlides">

    <?php query_posts('showposts=4&cat=11'); ?>
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php $counter = 1; ?>
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div id="slide<?php echo $counter; ?>"><img src="images/slide<?php echo $counter; ?>.jpg" alt="Slide <?php echo $counter; ?> jFlow Plus" />
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="< ?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            </div>
            <?php $counter++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This method does not incorporate featured images. It assumes that you have images stored in `example.com/images/slide1.jpg` (etc.).

Comment: @Chip Bennett: there was no question about featured images.

Comment: @petermolnar see the comments below my answer.

Comment: OK, you did discussed it after I posted this solution, so I upvoted yours, which now includes featured images as well.

Comment: @petermolnar yeah... it was more a case of the question not being written as completely and specifically as it could have been; took a bit to get the OP to clarify what all was needed. :)